# Set UIImageView under a label, instead of giving the coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c

If you want to create an ImageView, then you need to create it like this:

```
    UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)] autorelease];
```

The x and y coordinates are 10, but what if you got a label or something else (a textview where you don't know how long the text will be) that is on the exact same place. How can you put the image that it will always show up under the label, so instead of giving the coordinates what can you do?

Comment: If you work with Storyboard you can put a ImageView where you want from library.

Comment: I'm not using storyboard

Comment: Why not just add a `UILabel` as subview to `UIImageView`?
`[imageView addSubview:yourLabel];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_yourLabel.frame.origin.x, _yourLabel.frame.origin.y, 100, 20)] autorelease];
```

then :

```
[yourView addSubview:imgView];
[yourView addSubview:_yourLabel];
```

Comment: Thanks, replace this _yourLabel.frame.size.origin.x with _yourLabel.frame.origin.x and its fine

Comment: @Shinonuma , yes you are right , haha , had a bad remember without xCode

Answer (score 2):

for this you can do two ways.

1.add your image view to your view after that add label or anything to your view then it overlaps the imageview but give the `backGroundColor` to clear color.

2.add that label to imageview and add the imageview to Self.view.

IMP:clear the `backGroundColor` of the object which is placed on the `UIImageView`.

Comment: You could then center both the imageview and the textview within the super view. In addition, you can get the size of a label before you set the text using `NSString sizeWithFont`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height and width also equal to `UILabel`

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yourLabel.frame.origin.x, yourLabel.frame.origin.y, yourLabel.frame.size.width,yourLabel.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
[self addSubview:imgView];
[self addSubview:yourLabel];
```